# magento Automatic product add works, but how add dropdown menu value?

Tags: magento, addition, product

i have this code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');


$product->setSku("productSKU");
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setName("Product name");
$product->setCategoryIds("2,3,4,5,6");
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(0,1));
$product->setDescription("Mydesc");
$product->setShortDescription("mydesc2");
$product->setPrice(100);
$product->setWeight(5.00);
$product->setVisibility(4);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setTaxClassId(1);
$product->setStockData(array(
   'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 10
));
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
$product->save();
```

And works perfect.

Butt, now i need to add here one attribute, called “tyretype”.
I added few rows dropdown in that attribute, example “100”, “101”, “102”.

Now, if product have tyretype=101, how i add that value in that code ?

Please help, thank you.

And im running with magento 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,fetch option option value and option id of attribute using below code

```
$attributeBasictyretype = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'tyretype');

      if ($attributeBasictyretype->usesSource()) {
      $optionsBasic = $attributeBasictyretype->getSource()->getAllOptions(false,true);
      }
```

**$optionsBasic** give list of option ids and option name(Labels) **in array format**.

If you want to add option to product then you need to
 add set option id  to product.

```
  /*  Suppose: 100 option id is 15,101 option id is 17,102 option id is 13,then */

   /*if  attribute    tyretype  is multi select */
    $product->setTyretype(array(15,17,13));
//if  attribute is dropdown.you can add only option
    $product->setTyretype(15);
```